# SQL Server define a group using a name list

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a simple query that counts different types of tickets by departments.
There are 5 departments.  The query currently groups by dept.

```
SELECT 
    Dept_Name, COUNT(vsrv.TicketNbr) AS TotalTicketsSubmitted, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN vsrv.Closed_Flag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalTicketsClosed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN vsrv.Closed_Flag = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalOpenTickets          
FROM 
    v_rpt_service vsrv 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    v_rpt_SurveysByTicket vsrvy ON vsrv.TicketNbr = Vsrvy.SR_Service_RecID  
WHERE 
    Dept_Name IN ('Application', 'Support', 'Service', 'Development', 'IT')
GROUP BY 
    Dept_Name
```

What I need is to do is group the ticket counts so Group1 is just 'Application' and Group2 is the rest of the departments.

Is there a way to define the groups by the `Dept_Name`?

Something like this if possible...

```
SELECT 
    Dept_Name, COUNT(vsrv.TicketNbr) AS TotalTicketsSubmitted, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN vsrv.Closed_Flag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalTicketsClosed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN vsrv.Closed_Flag = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalOpenTickets          
FROM 
    v_rpt_service vsrv 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    v_rpt_SurveysByTicket vsrvy ON vsrv.TicketNbr = Vsrvy.SR_Service_RecID  
WHERE 
    Dept_Name IN ('Application', 'Support', 'Service', 'Development', 'IT')
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS 
    ((Dept_Name), ('Application'), ('Support', 'Service', 'Development', 'IT'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grouping for this. Something like this should work for you.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Dept_Name = 'Application' then Dept_Name else 'Group2' end as DepartmentName
    , COUNT(vsrv.TicketNbr) AS TotalTicketsSubmitted
    , SUM(CASE WHEN vsrv.Closed_Flag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalTicketsClosed
    , SUM(CASE WHEN vsrv.Closed_Flag = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalOpenTickets          
FROM v_rpt_service vsrv LEFT OUTER JOIN v_rpt_SurveysByTicket vsrvy ON vsrv.TicketNbr = Vsrvy.SR_Service_RecID  
WHERE Dept_Name in ('Application', 'Support', 'Service', 'Development', 'IT')
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Dept_Name = 'Application' then Dept_Name else 'Group2' end
```

Comment: I did not know that I could use a CASE statement in Group By.  I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be helpful for you. I assumed the `DEPT_NAME` column is from `v_rpt_service`. If not replace it with `v_rpt_SurveysByTicket`

```
SELECT Dept_Name, COUNT(vsrv.TicketNbr) AS TotalTicketsSubmitted, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN vsrv.Closed_Flag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalTicketsClosed,
        SUM(CASE WHEN vsrv.Closed_Flag = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalOpenTickets          
FROM (
    Select v_rpt_service.* -- all fields other than Dept_Name
        , CASE Dept_Name
            WHEN 'Application' THEN 'Group 1'
            ELSE 'Group 2'
        END AS Dept_Name
    FROM v_rpt_service
    ) vsrv 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN v_rpt_SurveysByTicket vsrvy ON vsrv.TicketNbr = Vsrvy.SR_Service_RecID  
WHERE Dept_Name in ('Application', 'Support', 'Service', 'Development', 'IT')
GROUP BY Dept_Name
```

Comment: THanks for your response.  I will keep it in mind if I cannot use the answer below for some reason.